# Filipino working in Dubai, need visa to visit Spain?

Tags: spain, dubai, filipino-citizens, visas-on-arrival

My niece and her husband are both working in Dubai, she is a nurse and he is an engineer. I live in Spain we have a house here. They would like to visit me for a short vacation. Do they need a visa to come to Spain? What are the requirements? We are Filipinos. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filipinos require a visa to come to Spain and you should apply at the local embassy for a [Short Term Visa](https://uae.blsspainvisa.com/short_term_visa_tourist.php)

You can find all of the information on the embassy website but to summarize:

- The fee would be 263 AED per person.
- Filled and signed application form.
- An original letter from the local (UAE) sponsor. This may be referred
  to as an NOC there.
- Passport meeting the validity requirements.
- Recent passport sized photograph.
- Photocopies of the passport along with the UAE visa page.
- Medical insurance.
- Proof of residence which in your case would be a "Carta de
  invitación" stamped by spanish police authority.
- Proof of financial guarantees.
- Return ticket booking.

The minimum process time of the application submitted in the UAE is 3 weeks so keep that in mind while making travel plans.

I believe they will need to [Book an Appointment](https://uae.blsspainvisa.com/book_appointment.php) with the embassy. Someone correct me if otherwise.

For details you can contact the embassy

> BLS International Spain Visa Application Center, I Rise Tower; 16 th
>   Floor, Office # C-9,  Barsha Heights (Tecom), Dubai, UAE.Phone: +971 2
>   5524492 Email: info.auh@blshelpline.com

Comment: Very helpful information. Thank you very much Newton ...

Comment: Please mark the answer if it was satisfactory so that the question doesn't remain unasnwered. Thanks.

Comment: @user56588 you can click the check mark below the voting buttons to "accept" the answer.